# Installing omise on opencart 2.2

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module, omise

I am trying to install Omise on Opencart 2.2(the latest one), but the latest Omise is only compatible with Opencart 1.5X, where the tutorials provided are also for Opencart 1.5X. So is there anyway,that will let me install Omise on Opencart 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Omise also supports OpenCart 2.0.x. Please find more information from this link: https://github.com/omise/omise-opencart

But for your asking version, OpenCart 2.2, You need to test it by yourself.